# Example of a semigroup satisfy some properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations

I want to find an example a finite semigroup $S$ and $K \subseteq S$  satisfy the  properties

- For any $a,b \in K$, we have $a,b \in \langle c \rangle$ for some $c \in S$.
- $K$ does not hold closure property.

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal example: take the semigroup $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$ equipped with the operation $x* y = \min\{x+y, 4\}$ and $K = \{2\}$. Then $2 = 1 * 1$, but $2 * 2 = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=<\mathbb Z_6,+>$ and $K=<\{1,5\},+>$.

Comment: In your example, $K$ is closed.

Comment: @user120386 $1+1=2\not\in K$.

Comment: You have written $K$ is generated by $1, 5$.

Comment: No! $K$ is a set with operation $+$.

Comment: You are welcome! Just my teacher, professor G.Dorofeev, wrote a set $A$ with operation $*$ like $<A,*>.$